# how to use string values declared in a void method of class1 in void method of class2 using C#?

Tags: c#

i have class1 and class2 in two different test files. a string should be declared in class1 method with void return type. then use that string value in class2 method with void return type. the sample script of what i want is as following.

*Testfile1*

```
public class Class1
{ 
    public string test1{get; set;}

    public void method1()
    {
       test1 = "xyz"; 
    }
}
```

*Testfile2:*

```
using test1;

public class Class2
{
    Class1 Obj = new Class1();

    public string test2;

    public void method2()
    {
        test2 = Obj.test1;
    } 
}
```

---

Actual script files in my coded ui project where i need to extract value for 'test' from 'prodSearch_ND' method.

TestFile1:

```
  /// <summary>
/// Summary description for CodedUITest
/// </summary>
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest:GenericFunctionsLib
{
    public string WinTitle { get; set; }
    public string EntityId { get; set; }

    ProdSearchValues_CO Obj_CO = new ProdSearchValues_CO();
    CreateWellValues_ND Obj_ND = new CreateWellValues_ND(); 



    [TestMethod]
    public void prodSearch_ND()
    {
        EntityId = Obj_ND.EntityId_ND;

        WinTitle = "CATS Energy - NorthDakota";

        this.ProdSearch1.RecordedMethod1();


        //this.ProdSearch1.AssertMainForm();
        //this.ProdSearch1.AssertProdTree();
        //this.ProdSearch1.ClickProdSearch();
        //this.ProdSearch1.AssertEntityTextBox();
        //this.ProdSearch1.EnterEntityId();
        ////this.ProdSearch1.AssertEntityIdExists();
        //this.ProdSearch1.AssertEntityTab();


    }
```

TestFile2:

```
 [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")]
public partial class ProdSearch1
{
    CodedUITest Obj = new CodedUITest();
    public string test;


    /// <summary>
    /// RecordedMethod1 - Use 'RecordedMethod1Params' to pass parameters into this method.
    /// </summary>
    public void RecordedMethod1()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinTreeItem uIProductionSearchTreeItem = this.UICATSEnergyNorthDakotWindow.UIItemWindow.UIItemTree.UIProductionSearchTreeItem;
        WinEdit uITxtboxEntityIdentifiEdit = this.UICATSEnergyNorthDakotWindow.UIFactoryProdSearchWindow.UITxtboxEntityIdentifiWindow.UITxtboxEntityIdentifiEdit;
        WinButton uISearchButton = this.UICATSEnergyNorthDakotWindow.UIFactoryProdSearchWindow.UIToolStrip1ToolBar.UISearchButton;
        WinCell uIItem133001011821Cell = this.UICATSEnergyNorthDakotWindow.UIFactoryProdSearchWindow.UIListofEntitiesFoundwWindow.UIListofEntitiesFoundwTable.UIPdenSelectionrow1Row.UIItem133001011821Cell;
        #endregion

        Obj.prodSearch_ND();
        test = Obj.WinTitle;

        // Click 'Production Search' tree item
        Mouse.Click(uIProductionSearchTreeItem, new Point(74, 5));

        // Type '133001011821' in 'txtboxEntityIdentifier' text box
        //uITxtboxEntityIdentifiEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UITxtboxEntityIdentifiEditText;
        uITxtboxEntityIdentifiEdit.Text = test;

        // Click 'Search' button
        Mouse.Click(uISearchButton, new Point(25, 13));

        // Double-Click '133001011821' cell
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIItem133001011821Cell, new Point(53, 4));
    }
```

Comment: ***a string should be declared in class1 method with void return type*** That makes -10000% sense

Comment: test2 holds null value, i am working on coded ui. so my test method which will be executing is class1. while i execute class1, class2 methods are called. when class2 methods are called, class1 should pass value to test1 through its method and then execute class2 methods.

Comment: Are you sure if replace Obj.prodSearch_ND();test = Obj.WinTitle; with test = "CATS Energy - NorthDakota" it will work without "The agent process was stopped while the test was running"?

Comment: Yes i tried that multiple times after replacing. I get the same error.

Comment: RecordedMethod1() is calling Obj.prodSearch_ND(); and inturn prodSearch_ND() tries to call RecordedMethod1(). which is throwing the above mentioned error.   
but i want 'test = Obj.WinTitle;'

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing `method1` on `Class1` instance, thus `test1` property have default value, which is `null`. In order to change state of `Class1` instance, you should call `method1`:

```
public class Class2
{    
    Class1 Obj = new Class1();

    public string test2;

    public void method2()
    {
        // at this point Obj has default value of test1 property
        Obj.method1(); // change state of Obj
        test2 = Obj.test1; // now test1 has value "xyz" assigned
    }    
}
```

NOTE: In C# we use PascalCase for public members and type names. Also we use camelCase for private members and local variables names.

If you want `Class1` to have "xyz" assigned to `test1` by default, you should assign this value in constructor of `Class1`.

Comment: Info on note - For the lazy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: i get this error and i am asked to close the program. "The agent process was stopped while the test was running" when i execute the script you suggested.

Comment: to be more clear, method1 is actually collection of different methods for different actions on the form, like 'click' action, 'type' action. method1 is coded ui type of method defined under [TestMethod]. method2 is a general class method.

Comment: @user3239627 C# is not script language. Code above works fine with class definitions you provided in question. And your explanation *'method1 is actually collection of different methods for different actions'* is not clear at all. Method is method. Collection is collection. Different things

Comment: I have edited my post with the real script where i need help. Please check.

Comment: @user3239627 so, what is your problem now?

Comment: RecordedMethod1() is calling Obj.prodSearch_ND();  and inturn prodSearch_ND() tries to call RecordedMethod1(). which is throwing the above mentioned error.

Comment: but i want 'test = Obj.WinTitle;'

Comment: @user3239627 that is something specific to CodedUITest and very different from your original question. I suggest you to rollback question edits and ask new question with appropriate code and error description. Side note - looks like you have recursion here - `RecordedMethod1()` calls `prodSearch_ND()` which calls `RecordedMethod1()` etc

Comment: Sergey Berezovskiy , you are right. Thanks Everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you want this, but you can change method2 like this

```
public void method2()
{
  Obj.method1();
  test2 = Obj.test1;
}
```

**UPDATE**

You wrote

RecordedMethod1() is calling Obj.prodSearch_ND(); and inturn prodSearch_ND() tries to call RecordedMethod1(). which is throwing the above mentioned error.

If I understood you right it means that problem has the same name like this project - Stack overflow. prodSearch_ND() tries to call RecordedMethod1() and inside RecordedMethod1() prodSearch_ND() is called again. It's infinite recursion that causes stack ovwerflow.

Comment: I get this error and i am asked to close the program "The agent process was stopped while the test was running" when i execute the script you suggested.